# Is there a way to require USB drives that are connect a Mac OS X to be encrypted?

Tags: macos, encryption

I have a customer who is concerned that the staff might be using USB drives to move data around.  They would like to require that these drives are encrypted with TrueCrypt or other method.

Is there a way to require that they are encrypted before they are accepted on the Mac OS X device?

Comment: NSA should done that to prevent Edward Snowden from stealing the data!

Comment: @Buscar웃 you're a riot. A true hoot-and-a-half

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this article, [New USB Enforced Encryption Device for Mac OS](http://www.darkreading.com/new-usb-enforced-encryption-device-for-mac-os/d/d-id/1141572), and possible solutions:

> It has always been a challenge for IT administrators to find solutions
>   and tools compatible with Mac OS X, but now securing the network and
>   data Mac users access is also becoming a priority.
>
> [CoSoSys](http://www.endpointprotector.com/solutions/usb_lockdown_for_mac)' Endpoint Protector 4 with Enforced Encryption on
>   removable storage devices for Mac OS X solves these problems.
>
> It offers an easy, yet secure way for Mac users to encrypt data copied
>   onto USB storage devices. With intuitive 'drag & drop' and copy/paste
>   features, all information copied on the device is instantly protected
>   by password-based military strength AES 256-bit encryption. The
>   Enforced Encryption functionality also incorporates an additional
>   security feature that deletes information if an attempt is made to
>   tamper with the data, or when the device gets lost or stolen.

<sub>Therefore, **stopping users from taking classified information** from Macs minis, iMacs, Mac Pros, MacBooks onto portable devices has become an imperative for the companies' data security. Locking down and monitoring proactively the use of USB, CD/DVD, card readers, etc. is possible with Device Control by Endpoint Protector for Mac OS X and can be managed centrally from the intuitive web-based interface.</sub>